# PHP Service Function Call Error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: php, .net, web-services, object-reference, wsdl2php

I'm having an annoying difficulty using a webservice written in .Net.
Wsdl can be found: http://services.odeontours.com.tr/OdeonWebService.asmx?wsdl

I want to call CategoryList function and its service description can be found [here](http://services.odeontours.com.tr/OdeonWebService.asmx?op=CategoryList)
I believe it returns a variable .net DataSet data-type..

I've generated wrapper classes by using wsdl2php. Which can be found [here](http://www.burakkoksal.com/OdeonWebService.txt)

And the code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
include_once './OdeonWebService.php';

$odeonClient = new OdeonWebService();

$auth = new AuthHeader();
$auth->PartnerID = 434;
$auth->UserName = 'xmlReaderGoral';
$auth->Password = "856UD..";

$catListParams = new CategoryList();

$catListRes = $odeonClient->CategoryList($catListParams)->CategoryListResult;

print var_dump($catListRes);
?>
```

And it says me:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

By the way in service description i noticed that i should pass AuthHeader by header. I have no idea how to do it..

What am i doing wrong??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Mind adding pastebin links to the classes `CategoryList` and `OdeonWebService`?

Comment: already added them. look for the keyword "found here" :)

Comment: Thanks :), in order to declare `$catListparams` as a valid php object try adding a [`__construct`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) and returning `$this`.

Comment: Since its a wsdl webservice, have you tried just doing `curl` to it, with the appropriate GET headers?

Comment: Actually no. Unfortunately I dont have much curl experience. Any resource to recommend??

Comment: Besides how can i determine the appropriate GET headers? And please consider AuthHeader issue that i mentioned in the question.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29217/discussion-between-killrawr-and-donkeykong)